# Phoenix + ExUnit: where should I define global helpers?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ex-unit

I have using Phoenix + ExUnit for tests.

I have some `ExUnit.Case` files like `DataCase, ConnCase...` to define test helpers for my `Models, Controllers...`, but if I need to define a global helper that it's accessible from all my tests, where should I define it?

Comment: Just create a new module if it makes sense to.

Answer (score 7):

If this is just a matter of a single helper, put it into your `test/test_helper.exs`.

But as the project grows, it becomes harder to manage. The common approach is to create `test/support` folder, and modify your `mix.exs` in the following way:

1. Create a private function like this:

```rb
defp elixirc_paths(:test), do: ["lib", "test/support"]
defp elixirc_paths(_), do: ["lib"]
```

2. Modify your `Mix.Project.project/0` callback to include the following key/value pair:

```rb
elixirc_paths: elixirc_paths(Mix.env())
```

3. Put all the files containing modules needed in `test` environment only there, as `*.ex` files.

That way all of them will be compiled in `test` and discarded in all other environments.

Comment: I like second option, but about `test/test_helper.exs`, it isn't a module how I could add helpers to it?

Comment: Just define module(s) there.